# Creating a function that generates a sequence of integers alternating between the low & high ends of a range

Tags: functions

I am trying to generate functions that will produce an integer sequence alternating between high and low values from a given range.

Let $G$ be a function that generates a *particular* function of the type I am describing.

Let $f$ be the particular function generated by $G(20)$

At integer inputs, $f$ should produce the following outputs:
$f(1) = 1, f(2) = 20, f(3) = 2, f(4) = 19, ...$

The function can do anything before 1, after 20, and between integer values.

I want to have a logic-free(no min, max, piecewise, etc) way of generating this sequence. It will also be put into code, so the faster computer implementation the better.

My first thought was to create one function that produces[1,0,2,0,3,0 ...], one that produces[0, 20, 0, 19, 0, 18...] and then add them together.

I believe this can be done using the floor function combined with Euler's identity to cycle an exponent between 1 and -1, but it doesn't seem like the best way.

Please, if you have any ideas or suggestions, let me know. Thanks a bunch in advance :)

Comment: As a start, use something like $x\sin(x)+x$. You should be able to shift things around (I think) to get the numbers you want, and it alternates between $0$ and $2x$ (shifted, this happens at the integers. I think something like this can be made to work.

Comment: There are a lot of great answers so far but just for future reference $\min$ and $\max$ can be implemented without any logic. In particular, 
$$\max(a,b) = \frac{1}{2}(a+b + |a-b|)$$
and
$$\min(a,b) = \frac{1}{2}(a+b - |a-b|)$$

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis
That then comes down to how absolute value is calculated. How is that calculated without logic?

Comment: @loganrussell48 Well I assume that `abs` function is available. But even without that something like `x * ((x > 0) - (x < 0))` should also work and calculate the absolute value of `x` in most programming languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try
$$f(n) := \frac{n+1}2 (n\ \%\ 2) + \left(N + 1 - \frac n2\right) ((n + 1)\ \%\ 2)$$
where $\%$ is the remainder operator.

Answer (score 2):

The closed formula looks a little bit scary, but you can solve this problem with [Lagrange Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Every sequence of points $(1,x_1), (2,x_2), (3,x_3), \ldots, (n,x_n)$ is carved out by a degree $n-1$ polynomial. Moreover, finding this polynomial is algorithmic once you know what you want the points to be. You can find a description of the polynomials (and some example computations!) on the linked wikipedia page.

It's a bit tedious to find this polynomial by hand, but getting a computer to do it for you is quite easy. In particular, you can write some python code (etc.) to implement the $G$ function that you are interested in, by having $G(n)$ be the degree $n-1$ polynomial lagrange interpolating $(1,1), (2,n), (3,2)$, etc.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: As much as I find Lagrange Interpolation very interesting I don't think it's the best option to be implemented in code. For this particular case, the resulting polynomial is [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolating+polynomial+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22InterpolatingPolynomialCalculator%22%2C+%22data%22%7D+-%3E%22%7B1%2C20%2C2%2C19%2C3%2C18%2C4%2C17%2C5%2C16%2C6%2C15%2C7%2C14%2C8%2C13%2C9%2C12%2C10%2C11%7D%22) which I think will cause some problems.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis -- First, I didn't know Wolframalpha had a button for that. Very cool. Second, that's super reasonable. Particularly in light of Theophile's excellent answer there are better approaches. I kind of expected a neat trick which had better results, but I'm also always excited to evangelize lagrange interpolation -- I think it should be more widely known.

Comment: @HellaSurvivor My thoughts exactly. When I first learnt about Lagrange Interpolation I was super fascinated :)

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{(-1)^n+1}{2}$ gives you $f(n)$ is 1 if n is even and 0 if n is odd.
Take that and multiply by 21.5. Then add/subtract $\frac{n+1}{2}$ as appropriate.

$$21.5 \frac{(-1)^n+1}{2} - (-1)^n \frac{n+1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
s(k) = \frac{1 + (-1)^k}{2} .
$$
That function's values alternate between $0$ and $1$.

If your range is from $1$ to $N$ then
$$
G(k) =  \frac{(k+1)s(k-1)}{2}  +   (N-(k-2)/2)s(k)  
$$
does the job.

If you have the $\%$ operator then the answer from @Théophile is better.